# Not able to setup Marklogic Java Api in local?

Tags: java, marklogic

I had installed ML 9.0.3 and followed this [document](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/java/setup) for setting up in my local and I edited `config.properties` to my requirement

```
# properties to configure the examples
example.admin_password=x
example.host=localhost
example.port=9963
example.authentication_type=digest
```

When I ran the first program in the console it is throwing error like this :

```
example: com.marklogic.client.example.tutorial.Example_01_CreateJSON
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No user provided
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.connect(JerseyServices.java:186)
    at com.marklogic.client.impl.JerseyServices.connect(JerseyServices.java:165)
    at com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(DatabaseClientFactory.java:156)
    at com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(DatabaseClientFactory.java:125)
    at com.marklogic.client.example.tutorial.Example_01_CreateJSON.main(Example_01_CreateJSON.java:37)
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems to indicate that no username was specified when it is attempting to connect on line 37:

```
DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient(Config.host, Config.port, Config.user, Config.password, Config.authType);
```

I don't see a username property in the properties that you provided. The tutorial shows the config.properties (which are missing from the properties you posed):

```
example.admin_user=rest-admin
example.writer_user=rest-writer
example.writer_password=x
```

The code for the Example_01_CreateJSON references the Config.user, which is obtained from the `example.writer_user` property:

```
protected static String user = props.getProperty("example.writer_user");
```

Your properties file must have an `example.writer_user` value defined, in order to know who to login as.